# jquery previous and next on click toggle

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to show and hide a div on click of previous and next. I am using jQuery toggle to achieve this. Below is what I have tried so far.

**HTML code**

```
<div id="one">a</div>
<div id="two">b</div>
<div id="three">c</div>

<div id="prev">prev</div>
<div id="next">next</div>
```

**jQuery Script**

```
jQuery(function(){
    jQuery("#two, #three").hide();
    jQuery("#next").on("click", function(){
        jQuery("#one, #two, #three").toggle();
    });
});
```

**Fiddle link**

https://jsfiddle.net/mqns2hy4/

So as you can see from the above, when I click on "next", I want only b to come and then when I click again, I wish to have c only and so on. Similarly on click of "Prev", I want the above to move in reverse and so on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could create one variable that holds index of active element and change that variable on click. Then you can hide all elements except one with the current active index.

```js
let active = 0;
let el = $("div");
let total = el.length - 1;

const toggle = (el, index) => {
  el.hide()
  el.eq(index).show()
}

toggle(el, active)

$('button').on('click', function() {
  this.id === 'prev' ? active -= 1 : active += 1;
  if(active > total) active = 0;
  if(active < 0) active = total
  toggle(el, active)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="one">a</div>
<div id="two">b</div>
<div id="three">c</div>

<button id="prev">prev</button>
<button id="next">next</button>
```

Comment: Thanks Nenad for the answer. It works fine on the fiddle, but when I add on my module, it hides everything. Not sure what can be the issue here.

Comment: @Nitesh You probably have to adjust selectors to your code instead of just using `$('div')` selector

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle with your actual html

Comment: Its huge code chunk. Let me see what I can do to truncate and represent only the relevant part.

Comment: ok I figured out the issue. I updated `$("div")` to `$("div#one, div#two, div#three")` and it now works fine. But is there a better way than adding each div id everytime to make it work? I tried doing it via parent child selector, but again everything got hidden. Accepted your answer and +1. Thanks.

Comment: @Nitesh There could be but then again, the selector will depend on the structure of your html.

Answer (score 1):

You could keep the index of the currently shown div:

```
 jQuery(function(){
   let index = 0;
   // you could also use a class to select them:
   let divs = ["#one", "#two", "#three"].map(it => jQuery(it));

   divs.forEach(it => it.hide());

   jQuery("#next").on("click", function(){
    divs[index].show();
    if(index > 0) divs[index - 1].hide();
    index++;
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks Jonas for the answer. The "next" works fine. Can you share updates about how the "prev" should work?

Comment: @nitesh no, I think you will be able to do that yourself :)

Comment: Certainly. Thank you for the efforts. +1 for the same.

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".page").hide();
    $("#page1").show();
});

$(document).on('click', "#next", function(){
    var pageCount = $(".page").length;
    var position = $(".page:visible").data('position');
    $(".page:visible").hide();
    if(position < pageCount){
        $("#page" + (position+1)).show();
    }
    else
    {
        $("#page1").show();
    }
});
$(document).on('click', "#prev", function(){
    var position = $(".page:visible").data('position');
    var pageCount = $(".page").length;
    $(".page:visible").hide();
    if(position > 1){
        $("#page" + (position-1)).show();
    }
    else
    {
        $("#page" + pageCount).show();
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="page1" data-position="1" class="page">a</div>
<div id="page2" data-position="2" class="page">b</div>
<div id="page3" data-position="3" class="page">c</div>

<div id="prev">prev</div>
<div id="next">next</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Zdenek for the answer. Is it possible to have "next" loop a,b,c again than just stop on c? Same for prev?

Comment: Thanks. +1 for the efforts. I will go with Nenad's answer.